# Java getter with Parameter?

Tags: java, oop

I am new to Java. I know about some core basics of Java such as setter and getter and recently came across a getter with a parameter (not sure if it is correct way of calling it):

```
public double getDistance(Point p)
{
   // what is inside here? Usually without the "Point p" I simply put "return distance;"
}
```

This method belongs to a class called Point and it is meant to get the calculation of distance from a private method in the same class.

I will appreciate if someone can enlighten me on the getter "parameter" and how I can apply the return in this method.

Thank you.

EDIT: Added the private calculation method

```
// Compute distance
private double distance(Point p)
{   
    double xx;
    double yy;
    double r;

    xx = this.x - p.x;
    yy = this.y - p.y;

    r = Math.sqrt(nx * nx + ny * ny);

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Well you're returning the distance. But the distance from what? I'm assuming you're returning the distance from `p`

Comment: Sorry if this isnt clear initially. I am returning distance from a private calculation method "private double distance (Point p)".

Comment: For what it's worth, despite the `get`, this isn't a "getter", which specifically takes no parameters.

Comment: just because the method name starts with `get` it is nothing special, you can do the same as done in `distance`. Or just return the value returned from calling `distance`

Comment: This method probably ought to have been called something like `distanceTo(Point p)`, rather than something starting with `get...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple argument rename will make things clear, you want to calculate the distance between two-points. Specifically, `this` point and `that` point. Assuming you have `double` `x` and `y` coordinates in each `Point` that might look like,

```
public double getDistance(Point that) {
    double tmpX = that.x - this.x;
    double tmpY = that.y - this.y;
    return Math.sqrt((tmpX * tmpX) + (tmpY * tmpY));
}
```

Comment: Hi Elliott! Thanks for answering. I have a method that is meant to do the calculation before the getter. I have modified my question above with this method. I don't understand how to insert the correct syntax or statement in the getter because there is a (Point p) in the parameter ().

Comment: `return distance(p);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Point2D`?  It has built-in methods for computing distances from a supplied point to some point you already have.

```java
      Point2D pt = new Point2D.Double(10,20);
      double distance = pt.distance(new Point2D.Double(20,30));
      System.out.println(distance);
```

Check it out at [java.awt.geom.Point2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html)